# What is "being" called grammatically?

Tags: present-participles

They weren’t **being** intentionally dishonest, just influenced by the conventional wisdom.

As a part of speech of "being" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Being" is a participle. In this case it forms part of the construction known as the "past progressive" or "past continuous": "they were being".